# In codeigniter - google login callback url containing special characters (.) and throwing 403 error. how to fix?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-authentication

http://techmarga.com/admin/login?code=4/fgDeyBqu0sgp4_FMWLm3TQCGgI54vUGKNCiW9g00TG4uOfd5Z_R_-uv4-25hoB-GsfrsPsFoBsxn0UwiLNcQZ78&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

In codeigniter google login callback url containing special characters and it is throwing 403 error. 
*if i remove https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile it is working** .

In local xampp everything is working fine but in server it is not working(403 error)

my config permitted_uri_chars are as below

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

[image]

Comment: Anyone please help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is not because of Codeigniter or google auth,this is because of modesecurity issue. I am using Bigrock hosting and they restricted mod security.After requesting to support team they enabled. Now it is working fine.

Comment: exactly ! some server provider block the rules.i've look inside my code for a long time.but problem is solved by just contacting to server Support Associate.