# Google auth showing HTTP 403 error forbidden

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, google-authentication, google-auth-library

As I run script on localhost works fine. but on server showing 403 error:
[image]

in my google console
for redirect url - 
 xyz.com/change/googlelogin

in my browser - after login with google auth it show me like - 
xyz.com/change/googlelogin?code=4/sgAnQ7T_O5l7bDPgaMQ4_s-c0Abz_wxsVPIt5bPQdaklIdF0QyoQicTXyW7CUQHh5ScUBZ4GYyyV8cZyiX-mu3s&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email  with above error

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.* Your question may be better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: You: "can you fix my car, it's not working"... me: "where is the car"...you: "I left it at home"...me: "well how I am I supposed to fix it then?". See a problem with that scenario? Same with your code...how can we possibly know what is going wrong without seeing the code, full error messages and (since it appears to be an issue only in one environment) any relevant configuration settings. We can only guess. Your question will get closed unless you can provide proper details. I'm not sure how you expected anyone to be able to magically guess your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of modesecurity restrictions from your hosting provider. Request them to disable for your domain. I was facing same issue ,i contacted support center and they fixed issue. Now it is working fine.

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52917870/in-codeigniter-google-login-callback-url-containing-special-characters-and)